# Read element in word (.doc)

Tags: element, .doc

I have built a program that is able to read .doc file and pass them to Cache database. I've done the passing part, but the problem is, how can I differentiate between paragraph and table content?

For example, I have **Section A** as a title and a table inside the section.

Currently, I just get the table content and send it as array to Cache Database. (ex. array(1,2))

I want to include the element **Section A** in the array.

It might look like this:

```
array(1)="Section A"
array(2,1,1)="Name: "
array(2,1,2)="Terry"
array(2,2,1)="Age: "
array(3)="Section B"
```

I like to set an ID for each element.

Comment: Anyone? Still stuck.